# Does ROW_NUMBER function work with NULL cast expression (RedShift)?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I got an error message from Redshfit for the following query:

```
SELECT relation_447.col_alias_1,
relation_447.col_alias_2,
relation_447.col_alias_3,
relation_447.col_alias_4,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY relation_447.col_alias_3 ORDER BY relation_447.col_alias_4 ASC) AS col_rnk
FROM (SELECT NULL::VARCHAR(60) AS col_alias_1,
X.A AS col_alias_2,
X.A AS col_alias_3,
Y.B AS col_alias_4
FROM X
LEFT JOIN Y ON X.A = Y.C) relation_447
```

Error message:

```
Amazon(500310) Invalid operation: ORDER/GROUP BY expression not found in targetlist;
```

However, if I replace the `NULL::VARCHAR(60)` phrase with `NULL::VARCHAR`, the query works fine.

Similarly a query with `NULL::NUMERIC` will fail. But if I replace that phrase with `NULL::BIGINT`, it will work again.

I was wondering if this is a bug or there is any solution for this issue?

Comment: found any solution to this ?

Comment: @GauravShah no. still waiting